# A sequence of whitespace added to the end of CHAR columns

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, t-sql, whitespace

Today I ran into a weird problem. I have a database in SQL Server which is filled with Linq data access layer. Now I've got some columns that are of datatype `CHAR(100)` for example .

When I`m inserting everything seems to be working fine but when I retrieve these values there some sequence of whitespace has been added to the end of each value.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Have you thought about doing the Trim of those values ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is expected behavior. [`char [(n)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) is a:

> **Fixed-length**, non-Unicode string data. n defines the string length and must be a value from 1 through 8,000. The storage size is n bytes. The ISO synonym for char is character.

Perhaps you mean to use [`varchar [(n | max)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) ?

> **Variable-length**, non-Unicode string data. n defines the string length
>   and can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the
>   maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size is the
>   actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for
>   varchar are char varying or character varying.

Comment: You mean that the added whitespace is normal and it happens all time (I mean to fixed-length chars ?) ?   And trimming the value to the end is what people normally do ?

Comment: `char` will always pad the data to be the fixed length you specified when creating the column. You would not normally use `char` if your data is not fixed-length, because of the hassle you are experiencing right now, anmong other things :)

Comment: Thnks alot ;) I`m gonna have to be reconsidering using fixed-length columns for that manner .

Comment: what people normally do is not use char unless they have a fixed length type of field (say 2 duigit state codes). VArchar is generally teh preferred choic fora field with variable length data.